# Convert hex binary to string in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, encoding, sitecore, sha1

So, I am trying to reverse engineer my way to find the right values here.

I am looking at this link: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/reset-admin-passord.html

and this link: https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/06/20/upgrading-the-password-hashing-algorithm-for-sitecore-9-installs/

```
UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership 
SET [Password]='qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc=', [PasswordSalt]='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw==', 
[IsApproved] = '1', [IsLockedOut] = '0'

    while len(@Salt) < 16
    begin
    set @Salt = (@Salt + cast(cast(floor(rand() * 256) as tinyint) as binary(1)))
    end
```

This is the code that Sitecore 7 uses to encode and hash the passwords in SHA1

```
-- Hash password
set @HashedPassword = HASHBYTES(@HashAlgorithm, @Salt + cast(@Password as varbinary(128)));

-- Convert hash and salt to BASE64
select @EncodedHash = cast(N'' as xml).value(
'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
, 'varchar(max)'
) from (select @HashedPassword as [bin] ) T

select @EncodedSalt = cast(N'' as xml).value(
'xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))'
, 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
) from (select @Salt as [bin] ) T
```

So, I have `password = 'b'` , `hashed_password = 'qOvF8m8F2IcWMvfOBjJYHmfLABc='` , `password_salt = 'OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFw=='`

The whole reason for this is that I need to get the Base64 encoded salt along with the Base64 encoded hashed password to migrate to another system (Okta).

If I was to reverse engineer my way in Python, what would this code look like?

```
import base64
import hashlib
import binascii

salt='OM5gu45RQuJ76itRvkSPFwi=='
password = 'b'

hashed_pw_salt = hashlib.sha1(hex_salt + password)
base64_hash = base64.b64encode(hashed_pw_salt.digest())
print base64_hash
```

I get the hashed password as 'VVNsI7GLzCRREOUcsha/+TbpGd8=' instead.

What is the best way to get the Python code to match the SQL code?

Comment: I don't have a solution to your issue, but one thing to consider would be if you need to keep the accounts at all. With newer versions of Sitecore, you can use federated authentication. Then users could use their existing accounts in Okta and access Sitecore with those credentials. 

You'd have to do some claims mapping to get them the right roles, but it might solve your issue?

Comment: @JayS That works if the users already exist in the identity provider but in many cases they do not, the identity provider is a new service. Therefore this is needed in order to avoid changing the user's password when they're migrated to the identity provider.